# How can i make a compact soft robot

Tags: actuator, manufacturing, soft-robotics

I want to make a compact (actuators motors and sensors are all in one) soft robot. Actuators can be pneumatic or dielectric. I need suggestions about manufacturating. I'm open to new ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think dielectric mechanism like piezo are suitable for compact designs.
These might be usefull
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piezoelectric_motor

https://www.google.com/patents/US4812698